# My function is not executing properly/completely after meeting condition

Tags: python-3.x, loops, tkinter-entry

I'm writing an enrollment program to enroll a large number of students and save their information in a database, however my function isn't running.

THIS is the sample code; I received no errors, so I'm not sure what's wrong.

```
# imported modules
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # creating instance of window stuff
    def erase(f):
        email.delete(0,"end")

    def erase1(e):
        name.delete(0,"end")

    # Password generator (To be sent on user's email)
    mxchars = string.ascii_letters+string.digits

    for pwd in range(1):
        pw = ''
    for c in range(10):
        pw += random.choice(mxchars)

    def aft():
        rot = tk.Tk()
        rot.title("zZ |Ξηr:book:llado")
        rot.iconbitmap(r"C:\PYTHON\Python310\share\Enrolladoico.ico")

        # Simply set the theme
        rot.tk.call("source", r"C:\PYTHON\Python310\Sun-Valley-ttk-theme-master\sun-valley.tcl")
        rot.tk.call("set_theme", "dark")

        # Set a minsize for the window, and place it in the middle
        rot.update()
        rot.minsize(rot.winfo_width(), rot.winfo_height())
        x_cordinate = int((rot.winfo_screenwidth() / 2) - (rot.winfo_width() / 2))
        y_cordinate = int((rot.winfo_screenheight() / 2) - (rot.winfo_height() / 2))
        rot.geometry("+{}+{}".format(x_cordinate, y_cordinate))

        # Panedwindow
        paned = ttk.PanedWindow()
        paned.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=(0, 0), sticky="news", rowspan=100)

        # Pane #1
        pane_1 = ttk.Frame(paned, padding=0)
        paned.add(pane_1, weight=0)


        # Notebook, pane #2
        pane_2 = ttk.Frame(paned, padding=5)
        paned.add(pane_2, weight=0)

        # Notebook, pane #2
        notebook = ttk.Notebook(pane_2)
        notebook.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

        # Tab #1
        tab_1 = ttk.Frame(notebook)
        for index in [0, 1]:
            tab_1.columnconfigure(index=index, weight=0)
            tab_1.rowconfigure(index=index, weight=0)
            notebook.add(tab_1, text="The Development of Enrollado")

        # Label
        label = ttk.Label(tab_1,text="‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎",justify="center",font=("-size", 104, "-weight", "bold"),)
        label.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=10, columnspan=2)

        # BG image
        introu = Image.open(r"C:\PYTHON\Python310\share\form.jpg")
        intr = ImageTk.PhotoImage(introu)
        intro = ttk.Label(tab_1,image=intr)
        intro.place(x=0, y=0)

        # Intro label
        fr = ttk.Label(tab_1,text="The goal of this system is to assist admissions staff in enrolling more students.\nThis system was devised in order to make the enrollment process for the\nupcoming school year 2022–2023 more efficient and effective in the most convenient\nway possible. There were several problems faced throughout the development of this system, but\nI was capable of completing it in a short timespan, which improved my programming expertise. ",justify="center",font=("-size", 23, "-weight", "normal"),)
        fr.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=170, columnspan=1)

        # LOGO image
        ing = Image.open("C:\PYTHON\Python310\share\Enrolladopng.png")
        imng = ImageTk.PhotoImage(ing)
        label5 = ttk.Label(tab_1,image=imng)
        label5.grid(row=0, column=0)


        # Tab #2
        tab_2 = ttk.Frame(notebook)
        notebook.add(tab_2, text="Enrollment form")

        # BG image
        intou = Image.open(r"C:\PYTHON\Python310\share\intro.jpg")
        inr = ImageTk.PhotoImage(intou)
        inro = ttk.Label(tab_2,image=inr)
        inro.place(x=0, y=0)

        ##############
```

THIS PART IS RELATED TO THE CODE ABOVE. IT EXECUTES THE FUNCTION WHICH DOESN'T SEEM TO EXECUTE COMPLETELY

```
    def entries_check():

        mail = email.get()
        fname = name.get()
        
        # import re module
        import re
        
        # Make a regular expression for validating an Email
        
        regex = r'\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z|a-z]{2,}\b'
        # define a function for validating an email
        
        if(re.fullmatch(regex, email.get()))and 'makatiscience.edu.ph' in email.get():
                # some email stuff
            else:
                aft()
        else:
            email.state(["invalid"])
```

Comment: There's little point in repeating "THIS is the sample code; I received no errors, so I'm not sure what's wrong.".   As far as I can see, you're not calling ```entries_check```

Comment: Yes it's in the body of the if __name__ == '__main__': block

Comment: I called it after declaring it

Comment: Then where are you calling ```entries_check```?  And what do you mean it doesn't ```execute completely```?

Comment: in another function which checks the credentials

Comment: it just opens up a new window. it works differently when separated from the whole program.

Comment: can you possibly solve my problem?

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's not possible to solve your problem because your post is still not clear (at least to me).  Please take the time to edit your post, ensure all relevant code is in the post as well as describe the behaviour you  want, and what you're actually getting.  Please be as clear what you mean by not 'executing completely'